# New Product Widget not appearing when adding phtml to theme

Tags: widget, new-products

I'm trying to add a New Product widget to my home page.  As soon as I had the new_list.phtml into my theme from the base theme, the widget disappear.

Has anyone encounter that issue in Magento ver. 1.9.2.2?